# Lasso of sparse linear regression model

Tags: st.statistics

Consider the sparse linear regression model $y=X\theta^*+w$, where $w\sim N(0, \sigma^2 I_{n\times n})$ and $\theta^*\in R^d$  is supported on a subset $S$. Suppose that the sample covariance matrix $\hat{\Sigma}=X^TX/n$ has its diagonal entries uniformly upper bounded by 1, and that for some parameter $\gamma>0$, it also satisfies an $\ell_{\infty}$-curvature condition of the from
$$\|\hat{\Sigma}\Delta\|_\infty\ge \gamma\|\Delta\|_\infty, \, \Delta\in C_3(S)
$$
where $C_3(S):=\{\Delta\in R^d: \|\Delta_{S^c}\|_1\le 3 \|\Delta_{S}\|_1\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof you are looking for should be in

> Theorem 1 of *Sup-norm convergence rate and sign concentration property of Lasso and Dantzig estimators* by Karim Lounici (https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4610).

Check the relationship of your curvature condition with Assumption 2 of that paper. The proof there should give you the main ideas, in particular the standard argument to prove that $\hat \theta-\theta^*\in C_3(S)$.

This proof fails for random design matrices when $|S|>>\sqrt n$ because the curvature condition in $\ell_\infty$ norm cannot hold. It is possible to overcome this difficult for Gaussian random design matrices, see

> Theorem 5.1 in *De-Biasing The Lasso With Degrees-of-Freedom Adjustment*
> by Bellec and Zhang (https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08885)

Comment: Thanks! How about this similar question? I just found someone asked for it. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417810/sparse-linear-regression-model